# Remove redundant column for composite key in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm, annotations

Hibernate creates empty "ID" column in case of code like in this post.

How tune it to not create "ID" column ("ID" is exact name of created column) or this can not be changed?

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "CATEGORY_RELATIONS")
    public class CategoryRelations implements Serializable {
    private CategoryRelationsPrimaryKey id;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_RELATIONS_CATEGORY_ID")
    private String categoryId;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_RELATIONS_PARENT_ID")
    private String parentId;
    //getters and setters
    @Entity
    @IdClass(CategoryRelationsPrimaryKey.class)
    public class CategoryRelationsPrimaryKey implements Serializable {
        protected long categoryId;
        protected long parentId;
        //euqals, hashCode
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `@IdClass` should stand at entity, not at composite id class;

2) If you already marked id properties by `@Id`, no separate `id` property is required:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY_RELATIONS")
@IdClass(CategoryRelationsPrimaryKey.class)
public class CategoryRelations implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_RELATIONS_CATEGORY_ID")
    private String categoryId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_RELATIONS_PARENT_ID")
    private String parentId;

    //...

}

public class CategoryRelationsPrimaryKey implements Serializable {
    protected String categoryId;
    protected String parentId;
    // ...
}
```

If you need some property named `id`, make it `transient` to avoid mapping to a DB table column.